# What do you call the clips for attaching a dado rail?

Tags: repair, walls, trim

The dado rail in our living room is attached with plastic clips that have kind of grove on them. Researching online, it seems that most people have stuck these rails on with glue.

[image]

Some of these are broken but I cannot find what they are called or where to buy them either online or in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could.. well, you could make your own using cut up gift cards or credit cards. It won't be as nice as the originals, but I think the plastic would be the right material.

Could you put up a photo of the groove this snaps into?

Comment: In retrospect, it looks similar to 80/20 T-Slot covers. They also come in many sizes, so you'll likely find one that'll match.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever seen them sold with the dado itself and not individually also they are somewhat uncommon now!